# display images served from a server, in a modal when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

here is my pug code:

```
    div.container-fluid
      #preview-section.mt-5 
        h5 Preview Files 
        hr 
        .row.row-cols-1.row-cols-md-4.g-4
          each image in images
            .col-md-4
              .card.clickable(data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal")
                img.card-img-top(src=image.dataUrl, alt=image.filename)
                .card-body 
                  h5.card-title= image.filename
        div.modal.fade#exampleModal(tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index: 1050;")
          div.modal-dialog.modal-lg(role="document")
            div.modal-content
              div.modal-body
                img#fullImage(src, alt)
              div.modal-footer
                button.btn.btn-secondary(type="button" data-dismiss="modal") Close
    script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js")
    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js")
    script(src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js")
    script(src="javascripts/test.js")
```

and javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clickable').forEach(clickable => {
    clickable.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const dataUrl = clickable.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
      const filename = clickable.querySelector('.card-title').innerText;
  
      const fullImage = document.querySelector('#fullImage');
      fullImage.setAttribute('src', dataUrl);
      fullImage.setAttribute('alt', filename);
  
      const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('#exampleModal'));
      modal.show();
    });
  });
```

problem is that when i click on the clickable, it displays the modal, just that it doesn't display the image, just an empty division, that strangely appears below the script tags with viewed on the webconsole